# toggle class on multiple elements react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got rendered array of filters, by clicking on element I'm pushing them to `selectedProperties` array, and also I want to set active class on element if it in array. How to do it properly with react? I got next code

```
...
render(){
  const {selectedProperties} = this.state;
  let classnames = classNames('box', {
    'active': '' //what condition apply here to set class?
  });
return (
  <div className="hotel-filter">
    <div className="filter-label">Что для вас важно?</div>
    <div className="filter-options">
      <ul className="priorities-boxes">
        {
          this.state.priorities.map(item => {
            return (
              <li key={item.id}
                  className={classnames}
                  onClick={(evt) => this.selectValue(item.id)}>
                <img src={`/images/filter-icons/${item.icon}`} />
                <span>{item.name}</span>
              </li>
            )
          })
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
)
}
```

I'm using classnames utility to add class dynamically but my condition is wrong.

Comment: On your `let classnames`, `item.id` is not defined?

Comment: yes. and actually I don't know what condition apply there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the reference to `item` in order to check it is in the selected array, which cannot be done outside the loop, otherwise all would be the same, so just do it inside the loop instead for each item

```
render(){
  const {selectedProperties} = this.state
  return (
    <div className="hotel-filter">
      <div className="filter-label">Что для вас важно?</div>
      <div className="filter-options">
        <ul className="priorities-boxes">
          {
            this.state.priorities.map(item => {
              return (
                <li key={item.id}
                    className={classNames('box', {
                      active: selectedProperties.includes(item.id)
                    })}
                    onClick={(evt) => this.selectValue(item.id)}>
                  <img src={`/images/filter-icons/${item.icon}`} />
                  <span>{item.name}</span>
                </li>
              )
            })
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Tried just now, not helped. I click on element and nothing changed. (

Comment: Well this will work as long as `this.selectValue` is actually updating the `selectedProperties` array. You don't show that so we can't diagnose

Comment: you right, I forget to call `setState` after push in array.

Comment: great glad its fixed!

Answer (score 2):

This might resolve issue with multiple element class toggling.try this out:

https://jsfiddle.net/menomanabdulla/todu7m6g/11/

```js
class ToggoleApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    
    }
    
    this.toggleClass=this.toggleClass.bind(this);
    
  }
  
   toggleClass(e){
        let classes = 'my-class';
        let els = document.getElementsByClassName('my-class active');
        if(els){
            while (els[0]) {
                els[0].classList.remove('active')
            }
        }
        e.target.className = classes.replace('my-class','my-class active');
    }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Toggle Example</h2>
        <ul>
          <li className="my-class active" onClick={(e) =>this.toggleClass(e)}>
            One
          </li>
          <li className="my-class" onClick={(e) =>this.toggleClass(e)}>
            Two
          </li>
          <li className="my-class" onClick={(e) =>this.toggleClass(e)}>
            Three
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ToggoleApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.my-class{
  color: #FF3355;
}
.my-class.active{
  color: #33FF46;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: one doubt why we are using while loop? even without it, its working fine for me.

Comment: umm! what about remove active class from previous elements? while is play main role as toggling here.

Answer (score 0):

```js
class ToggoleApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    
    }
    
    this.toggleClass=this.toggleClass.bind(this);
    
  }
  
   toggleClass(e){
        let els = document.getElementsByClassName('my-class active');
        if(els){
            while (els[0]) {
                els[0].classList.remove('active')
            }
        }
        e.target.className = 'my-class active'
    }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Toggle Example</h2>
        <ul>
          <li className="my-class active" onClick={(e) =>this.toggleClass(e)}>
            One
          </li>
          <li className="my-class" onClick={(e) =>this.toggleClass(e)}>
            Two
          </li>
          <li className="my-class" onClick={(e) =>this.toggleClass(e)}>
            Three
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ToggoleApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```